# Does having "More details" on when copying a file make the copying go slower?

Tags: windows-8

When I turn "More details" on:

[image]

Does it go slower than having "Fewer details" on:

[image]

In this case, I'm copying from my internal drive to my external, but what would happen if I was copying a file from my internal to internal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not make any difference. When you don't click on more details that doesn't mean that the details are not calculated, the additional information is present even if you don't click on the more details. It does not matter from where to where you are copying your files clicking on more details button wan't slow down the process.

Comment: In all likelihood, not all statistics would be calculated if they weren't requested, but considering file copying is generally an I/O-bound activity, the extra CPU load makes no difference ultimately.